# Problem on Inclined Forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

I am having trouble on one of my homework problems. 
The problem is

> *What is the acceleration of the system if M1 is 5 kg and M2 is 4kg and the coefficient of friction between M1 and the table is 0.20?
>   There is an image along with the problem. Basically it is just like a standard inclined plane problem where M1 is the box on the ramp and M2 is the weight being pulled down.  The angle of incline is 40degrees.*

The teacher stated that the answer was $0.02 m/s^2$, but that we would have to show all work to recieve credit. I have worked it out several times, but have not been able to get that answer. 
He taught is to do this by plugging values into the equations $T - mg = ma$ and $T - F_f = ma$, setting the tensions equal to each other, and finding the acceleration. I did this, but got something along the lines of $3.5 m/s^2$. I looked up alternative methods online, but they didn't seem to use the second equation, and I was a little confused. If someone would teach me the steps to solve this problem, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to solve the problem from first principles, deriving all the formulas you need in the process from Newton's laws and the problem statement. The two masses are connected by a rope which has some fixed length, this means that the magnitude of the acceleration of the box on the ramp is the same as the magnitude of the acceleration of the weight dropping downward.

Now, suppose that the magnitude of the acceleration is $a$, then this means that the magnitude of the total force acting on the weight is equal to:

$$F_2 = M_2 a$$

And this force is directed downward as it is accelerating in that direction. Gravity is acting on the weight with a force of $M_2 g$, therefore the force exerted by the rope on the weight is equal to:

$$F_{\text{rope}} = F_2 - M_2 g = M_2 (a - g)$$

Now $a<g$, so this is negative, meaning that the force exerted by the rope on the weight is directed upward (we used the magnitude of the total force and the force of gravity in the above equation, and they are postive in the downward direction, so the calculation above will yield the component of the force in the downward direction).

The force exerted by the weight on the rope in the downward direction is thus:

$$ T = M_2 (g - a)$$

Then if the rope is massless, the total force exerted on the rope equals zero.  If the rope were straight, you can immediately conclude that the force exerted on the rope on both sides is equal and opposite. In this case the rope isn't straight, and it's useful to define the so-called tension in the rope. The tension in the rope at some point is the magnitude of the force that the part of the rope on one side of the point exerts on the part on the other side of that point. What happens if the rope slides over a frictionless pully is that the pully exerts a force on the rope in the direction orthogonal to the rope, a balance of forces calculation then implies that the tension will remain the same, the effect of the force exerted by the pully is only to change the direction the tension force is oriented in, precisely according to the direction of the rope.

So, the tension at the point of the box is the same as at the point of the weight, the force exerted by the rope on the box is thus given by $T$. The component of the force exerted by gravity along the incline is $-M_1 g\sin(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the angle of the incline with the horizontal, and the normal force equals  $M_1 g\cos(\alpha)$. The normal force times the coefficient of friction $f$ gives you the magnitude of the friction force that acts along the incline. The total force acting on the box along the incline is thus:

$$F_{\text{box}} =  M_2 (g - a) - M_1 g\sin(\alpha) - M_1 g f \cos(\alpha)$$

Since the box has to accelerate at the same magnitude as the weight is falling, $F_\text{box} = M_1 a$, and we can solve for $a$:

$$M_1 a =  M_2 (g - a) - M_1 g\sin(\alpha) - M_1 g f \cos(\alpha)\Longrightarrow$$

$$a = \frac{M_2}{M1 + M_2}g - \frac{M_1}{M1 + M_2}g\left[\sin(\alpha) + f\cos(\alpha)\right]$$